# Javascript Function Date Range Modification

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to make my input type loggerTxt in date('F Y'); but I can't modify this log(data.dateFrom). I want to ask if it is possible to change it since I am a newbie.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    
            <h3>Range</h3>
            <input type="text" id="daterange">
            <input type="text" id="range-from">
            <input type="text" id="range-to">
            <input type="text" id="loggerTxt">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/duDatepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function log (message) {
                document.querySelector('#loggerTxt').value = message
            }
    
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                duDatepicker.defaults({ auto: true, theme: 'dark', format: 'mmmm d, yyyy' });
                
                duDatepicker('#daterange', {
                    range: true, outFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd', fromTarget: '#range-from', toTarget: '#range-to',
                    clearBtn: true, theme: 'blue', 
                    
                    events: {
                        
                        dateChanged: function (data) {
                            console.log('new date', data)
                            log(data.dateFrom)
                        }
                    }
                })
                
            })
        </script>
```

Comment: what is mmmm-yyyy???

Comment: sorry sample "August 2021"